# De-serialize derived type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I thought I finally understood XmlSerialization, but my last approaches let me feel like a total newbie on it. 
My intention is to create a framework that serializes and de-serializes some kind of configuration. Therefore I created a config-class as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Application-wide configurations that determine how to transform the features. 
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "baseNS")]
public class Config
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of all configuration-settings of this application
    /// </summary>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Setting")]
    public List<Setting> Settings = new List<Setting>();
}
```

Now I need some kind of configuration, that defines a custom settings-list.

```
/// <summary>
/// Application-wide configurations that determine how to transform the features. 
/// </summary>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Config", Namespace = "baseNS")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(BW_Setting))]
public class BW_Config : Config { 
    // nothing to add, only needed to include type BW_Setting
}


/// <summary>
/// Provides settings for one single type of source-feature specified by the <see cref="CQLQuery"/>-property. Only one target-featureType is possible for every setting. 
/// However settings for different targetTypes may have the same source-type provided. 
/// </summary>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Setting", Namespace = "anotherNS")]
public class BW_Setting : Setting {
    // add and modify some attributes
}
```

As far as I know I´d put the XmlInclude-attribute on the base-class (being Setting). Hence Setting and BW_Setting reside in different assemblies with the latter depending on the former I cannot use this approach because I´d get a circle-reference.

This is the code for the actual serializer:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BW_Config));
BW_Config c = new BW_Config();
c.Settings.Add(new BW_Setting());
((BW_Setting)c.Settings[0]).CQLQuery = "test";
```

Now when executing the above I get error `"Type BW_Setting was not expected. Use XmlInclude..."`
I may change everything within the custom assembly, but hence the base one belongs to the  framework I cannot change it. Can you help me to get serialization (and deserialization) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it work by defining some overrides:

```
// determine that the class BW_Setting overrides the elements within "Settings"
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(
    typeof(Config), 
    "Settings", new XmlAttributes { 
        XmlElements = { 
            new XmlElementAttribute("Setting", typeof(BW_Setting)) } });
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config), overrides);
```

This produces the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="baseNS">
  <Setting id="0">
    <CQLQuery>test</CQLQuery>
  </Setting>
</Config>
```

Only unpleasant thing is that the namespace within the XML for the tag Setting is lost. However deserialization also works, so that´s not as annoying.